# d3.js and nvd3.js how to show graph for number of clicks on a website

Tags: d3.js, time-series, nvd3.js

I want to give the user flexibility to choose the datetime range and see the graph of number clicks during that period. The range could be anything like 1 year, 6 month, 1 month, 1 week , 1 day or last 6 hours...
At any point of time there is exactly 1 click. So, my dataset is as :

```
Time                           Click
2012-01-01 01:00:00             1
2012-01-01 02:00:00             1
2012-01-01 03:10:00             1
2012-01-01 03:20:01             1
2012-06-02 11:00:00             1
2012-12-01 01:00:00             1
2013-05-01 12:00:00             1
```

The graph should be able to adjust it's x-axis as per what the data is available to it. For example if we are checking a days data then it should show HH:00 range and if we are looking for a week data then it should Mon-Tue-Wed like range.

My sample code looks like this:

```
 `chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(false).tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
  d3.select('#chart1 svg')
    .datum(jsonData)
      .call(chart);`
```

How to handle the aggregation of the data point? Do I have to provide the data set with the aggregation or chart can do it itself by providing it some function.

---

### Update

---

I tried with rollup and found it gives some aggregation to my data now.

```
rollup = d3.nest().key(function(d) {
          return (new Date(+d[0])).getMonth(); 
      }).rollup(function(d) {
        return d3.sum(d, function(e) { return +e[1]; });
      }).entries(jsonDataValues)
    .map(function(d) {data.push([d.key,d.values])});
```

It aggregates the data on basis of the month. It needs to be modified to be more flexible so that it adjusted itself for the given range (May be domain is my friend here ?)

Comment: You need to aggregate the data yourself. You also need to provide the functionality to specify and draw a given period yourself.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I tried with nest() and rollup(). I feel that I should be able to generate the data point with the help of these methods and therefore I have updated the question above with 'Update'. Could you please help on this.
jPivot provides this functionality inbuilt and also provide drill down at ease.

Comment: I would advise using jPivot then and maybe using the data it provides with D3 rather than rolling your own aggregation.